# Ideal value of max_allowed_packet in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

As per MySQL docs:

> 15.11: You get an ER_NET_PACKET_TOO_LARGE exception, even though the binary blob size you want to insert using JDBC is safely below the
>   max_allowed_packet size. This is because the hexEscapeBlock() method
>   in com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.streamToBytes() may almost double
>   the size of your data.

I am trying to insert a `BLOB (max. 10MB)`, while `"max_allowed_packet"` is set to 16MB.

Do I need to increase max_allowed_packet to 20 MB or we can handle it in any other way ?